# R: why do.call plot come with y values

Tags: r, plot

I am using `do.call` in building a function. but I met a problem like this:

```
z<-sample(1:3, 100, T)
y<-rnorm(100)
plot.list <- c(list(x=z,y=y))
do.call(plot, plot.list)
```

why the plot has included the `y` values?

Thanks!

Comment: because `plot` uses `deparse(substitute(.))` to try to retrieve the labels from the `x` and `y` variables that are passed; in this case they have already been evaluated, so you get junk.  You can either set the labels explicitly or try to come up with the appropriate `eval` incantation ...

Comment: Thanks, Ben! May you be able to give an example of the eval() using my example?

Comment: I couldn't figure it out quickly, which is why I only left a comment and not an answer ... @mnel's answer seems pretty good.

Comment: @BenBolker `evalq(plot(z,y))` might be the `eval` approach for which you were searching.

Comment: maybe not? because that wouldn't handle an arbitrarily specified list as input ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `plot.default` attempts to create sensible labels for `x` and `y` if `xlab` and `ylab` are `NULL`

Using

```
deparse(substitute(y))
```

However, using `do.call`, the list is created, and the variable known as `y` is replaced by its contents thus this approach renders the label with the entire variable

```
foo <- function(y) deparse(substitute(y))
> do.call(foo, list(y=y))
 [1] "c(1.19006018249756, -0.50627079218304, -0.103312348822805, 0.395028889714542, " 
 [2] "1.25258077222837, 2.63766225444435, 0.260296813253391, 0.280839960496168, "     
 [3] "-1.47428483557887, -0.585934600873922, 0.879979238185618, -0.0871689899965067, "
 ..... <truncated>
```

Setting `xlab` and `ylab` explicitly is the way to go.

```
do.call(plot, list(x=z,y=y, xlab = "x",ylab="y"))
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `do.call` you'd need to pass `z` and `y` as names so they don't get evaluated ahead of time.

```
do.call("plot", list(x=as.name("z"), y=as.name("y")))
```

But the code sure feels like it would be clearer if you set `xlab` and `ylab` explicitly as @mnel recommends.